# Sum up the amount of leave taken

Tags: python, django

I have a model which have one to many relationships, for instance, a user can apply for one or many leaves. I want to add up the number of leaves for each user and then group by the user but I am not sure how to do that. I did something as below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
def monthly_leave_taken(request):
    result = NewLeave.objects.values('user').annotate(Sum('Total_working_days'))
    return render(request, "result.html", locals())

class NewLeave(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_balances = models.ManyToManyField(Leave_Balance)
    leave = (
        ('annual', 'annual'),
        ('sick', 'sick'),

    )

    Leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=leave, blank=False, default='')

    Start_Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    End_Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    Total_working_days = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)
    Reason = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=False)
    Aut = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Rejected', 'Rejected'),
    )
    Manager_Authorization_Status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Aut, default='Pending', blank=False)
    Authorized_by_Manager = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=False)
    Authorised_Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    DirAuth = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Rejected', 'Rejected'),
    )

    Director_Authorization_Status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DirAuth, default='Pending', blank=False)
    Authorized_by_Director = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=False)
    Date_Authorized = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    arc = (
        ('', ''),
        ('Archived', 'Archived'),

    )
    Archived = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=arc, default='', blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Leave_type
```

Comment: Please share the relevant models.

Comment: I've updated my model

Comment: How is the result different than your expectation?  Its sounds like you want the count, which could be:  NewLeave.objects.values('user').annotate(user_cnt=Count('id'))

Comment: I just realize that the current code works, I try from the python shell and i get the result {'user': 2, 'Total_working_days__sum': 4.0}
{'user': 3, 'Total_working_days__sum': 23.0} but i am not sure how to pass the sum of the total_workinng_days and the user to the template so that i have two columns. one column for the users and another column for the sum of the total_working days.

Comment: i try something like this but it doesn't work
 <th>staff</th>
  <th>Total work days</th>

{%for leave in result%}

        <td>{{leave.user.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{leave.total_working_days}}</td>
    {%endfor%}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the users first_name, then it might make sense to run the query on the User model.

```
users = User.objects.annotate(new_leave_tot_w_days=Sum('newleave__total_working_days'))
```

In the template you can loop over the users and and access the "new_leave_tot_w_days" attribute.

```
{%for user in users %} <td>{{user.first_name}}</td> <td>{{user.new_leave_tot_w_days}}</td> {%endfor%}
```

Comment: i try that but i am getting an error django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'total_working_days' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.